# Envio de corrreo electronico

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla con numero inicial numero siguiente y numero final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo
vamos en el consecutivo 1020007744 y el consecutivo final es  1020021000,
necesito que faltando 10 o 20 números para llegar al #final osea cuando vamos en el numero 1020019980 me mande una notificación al correo electrónico que ya estamos llegando al final, como lo puedo hacer fácil y rápido 
alguna sugerencia  ¿?

Comment: Hola @Hackerman, si sabes ingles te recomiendo pasarte por esta pregunta realizada en StackOverflow ingles donde se explica como hacer un Trigger que mande un mail cuando se inserta en la base de datos. Espero que te sea util para tener un punto de partida. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger)

Comment: muchas Gracias amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer fácilmente con un trigger. Aquí lo tienes:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers
    WHERE name = 'TX_SEND_MAIL')
    DROP TRIGGER TX_SEND_MAIL
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TX_SEND_MAIL
    ON Results      
    AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @Sub_men Nvarchar(256), @Dif int = 10 -- 10 o 20 cantidad que falta para avisar
IF (SELECT (LastNum - NextNumber ) FROM Results ) = @Dif
    BEGIN
        -- PRINT 'Faltan ' + convert(nvarchar(3),@Dif) + ' numeros' -- Para verificar el valor quitar los dos "--" delante del PRINT
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'TuMail@mail.com', 
        @subject = 'El mensaje que decidas ' , 
        @body = 'El cuerpo del mensaje';
    END
GO
```

Lo he probado en SQL Server 2012 y 2016 y funciona correctamente.

Lógicamente debes permitir el acceso al procedimiento `dbo.sp_send_dbmail`  que por defecto viene desactivado por seguridad del server.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo